# Replace null with empty string in Play Json

Tags: scala, playframework, play-json

I have a json which has some null value in it, I just want to replace that null value with an empty string using play json.

Sample json:

```
{
  "featureLength": 348.4256690782206,
  "projectName": null,
  "total_Feature_Length": 348.43
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Are you sending or receiving the JSON?

Comment: @wwkudu  receiving

Comment: is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use two ways to "receive" JSON: the "ad hoc" way, and the "case class" way. In the ad hoc way you might have something like:

```
val projectName = (json \ "projectName").asOpt[String].getOrElse("")
```

which would accept a string or null and give you a string in the projectName variable. In the "case class" way, we define a Reads converter, say for case class `Feature`, and then

```
implicit val reads: Reads[Feature] = {
  ((__ \ "featureLength").read[Double] and
    (__ \ "projectName").read[Option[String]] and
    (__ \ "total_Feature_Length").read[Double]) ((length:Double, projectName:Option[String], totalLength:Double) =>
  Feature(length,projectName.getOrElse(""),totalLength))
}
```

which will convert the input to your case class and again, the `getOrElse` ensures that the incoming projectName, whether a string or a null will result in a string thereafter.

Comment: Sometimes you have to send this data to client and you can't send Option[String] so you have to convert it to string (empty or not). If we have Iterable[String] it makes it even worse as we need to use Iteralbe[Option[String]] for play json. If dataset is too big it's unnecessary iterating collection just to decide whether value should be replaced with empty string. Instead, Play json should be able to make that decision for any string field by itself. Look like you can do it adhoc way. It then should be possible case class way. my 2c